# Raspberry pi 3 B with Buster can't be pinged, wlan0 stuck in DORMANT

Tags: pi-3, networking, wireless, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to use the built-in wifi on my pi. I upgraded the OS on my Raspberry pi 3 B from Jessie to Buster. Since the upgrade, I haven't been able to ping my pi. I noticed that `ip link` showed `wlan0` as `DORMANT` so I turned off power management using `iwconfig`. However, while `iwconfig` is showing that power management is off right now, `ip link` is still showing that `wlan0` is `dormant`. `dmesg` also confirms on `reboot` that power management is disabled.

On the Pi, I have internet access and can ping sites. What I'm attempting to do is SSH into my pi from my desktop.

**Update** with info from comment:
To upgrade I turned off my Pi, formatted the SD card on my desktop, and imaged the Buster image to the SD card.

**Update 2**:
I bought a USB wireless adapter (Panda wireless N plug & play, rt2800usb). The Raspberry PI recognized it and was able to bring up the interface, but this interface was also stuck in `DORMANT` with the same conditions as the onboard wireless (Can ping external sites but it can't be pinged from devices on my home network). I also turned off power management for the new device (wlan1) but the link remains in `DORMANT`

Comment: "I upgraded the OS on my Raspberry pi 3 B from Jessie to Buster" i.e. you ignored the Foundation recommendations to do a fresh installation - apart from skipping Stretch!

Comment: @Milliways to upgrade I turned off my Pi, formatted the SD card on my desktop, and imaged the Buster image to the SD card. Would this be considered a fresh installation? If not, what steps should I have taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by having the computer that I was trying to ping the pi with plug into the router directly instead of having it plugged into a network switch that was plugged into the router.

As for the device being stuck in DORMANT mode, I fixed that using the following command: `ip link set wlan0 mode default`

Comment: It's unclear to me why this should be necessary. I understand that it was an issue in `jessie`, but the [current documentation doesn't mention it in their instructions for setting up the wifi.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/)

Answer (score 3):

Because you started with a fresh flashed Raspbian Buster image so just enable WiFi as described at [Wireless connectivity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md) from the Raspberry Pi Foundation. If this doesn't work then you should have a look at the hardware of your RasPi or at the device from which you try to connect.